# Disable photo sharing in IOS, Ionic2 native Photo Viewer plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using photo viewer plugin in Ionic-native in an Ionic2 app.

My code is `this._photoViewer.show(bookImgPath, '', {share: false});`

I have disabled the sharing, but sharing is enabled on Ios.

It is working in Android only.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can do that for **Android only**.There is **No** support for **iOS** yet.

> Optionally you can pass third parameter which can be used to hide the
>   share button [ONLY FOR ANDROID]

[**Official PhotoViewer Cordova Plugin Doc**](https://github.com/sarriaroman/photoviewer#show-an-image)